# Problems creating a Single

Tags: singles

I created a new single in Entries but the "preview" action isn't showing, which typically alerts me that I have not set it up correctly. In the singles list, if I click on the "blue globe" I get "couldn't find the page..."

to create the new single entry i did this:
Settings
Sections
New Section
Screen show of info in the section detail.
[image]

I know I am missing a very simply step because whenever I have to create this I always have this problem. But I can never recall how to fix it.

Comment: can you check if you have at least 1 website configured in "Settings > Websites" and if this primary site has its own URL configured? btw.: what Craft version are you using?

Comment: Settings>General Settings the site URL is listed
I don't see Settings>Websites
Craft 2.7.10

Comment: I'm attempting to set up a single that is not associated with a Channel or structure for a short term campaign that needs a simple URL.

Comment: OK: There is no "Settings > Websites" in Craft 2, there it is called "Settings > Locales" (I think...). Please check if there is at least one locale, because URLs depend on the locale.

Comment: Ok in Locales there is nothing except identifying "US English"

Comment: We have other singles set up this way and they are working

Comment: I figured it out! I forgot to identify which entry template to use. Under "Entry Template" I needed to use a different form, instead of letting it auto fill from the name of the single. Thanks!

Comment: happy that it's working :-)